# Positioning div relative to scaling slider

Tags: html, slider, css-position

I want to position a div on top of a slider for my wordpress page. I managed to show the div using z-index however I cannot position it correctly... The div loads after the scaling full-width slider and I use top: - 790 to lift the div towards the top of the screen however this only works for bigger screen sizes - Once I resize the window the div comes up way too much. I am pretty sure it needs to be something like this: top: -790 -x (x rises if screen size decreases).

Here is my custom css:

```
position: relative;     
top: -790px;
margin-left: 21px; 
z-index: 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of px, use % as a scaling factor,

Example

```
top:-790px;
```

instead use (of course change the percentage in accordance of your page)

```
top:-70%;
```

This will change when the screen size increases, ultimiatly changing the negative x value